# Should I test form validation and validation messages with unit tests or e2e tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

We use BDD for development and I have one question about testing. Should I test form validation and validation messages in unit tests or e2e tests?
I know that questions primary opinion based are not allowed, so I would like to have some kind of official article related to the answer.

Thanks a lot

Comment: The problem here is that the question is just too vague. Where are these messages and form? The answer is, 'it depends'.

Comment: @estus they are validation or error messages of the form. they appear on the fields or on the page. What does "where are these messages" means?

Comment: BDD is more like a blackbox test. You don't test the implementation, just how it behaves.

Comment: Hi @LeonardoVenoso thanks for your reply but I cannot understand so what s the answer to my question?

Comment: You should test the result message in BDD like a black box. You send a stimulus and the you get an answers. For that stimulus X you expect and answer Y.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who comes across this post. As @Leonardo Venoso pointed out, it is  much more preferred to test validations (form validations) in a black box. Since we only test for expected output like error messages, isolating it as unit test would be most effective.

On the other hand E2E test, we only test if a certain feature works as expected and it would be costly to test each underlying methods (in this case validations), so with E2E test we would only need to confirm whether the function or feature succeeded or failed. Since we already tested the validations as a unit test, we are confident that when the E2E test succeed, the validations are as well.